# How to extract values from a dictionary based on index

Tags: python, dictionary

Lets say I have one dictionary, one list with indexes that are not na, and indexes that are na. I want to extract the information based on each different object inside the dictionary with this list of indexes, but I want to know the key name of each object.

```
notna_idxs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, ]
na_idxs = [0, 5, 9]

dd = {
    0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
}
```

Then we can match the indexes continuously. In this case, the object 0 has the first 4 indexes (0,1,2,3,4) and the object 1 has the other indexes (5,6,7,8,9).
The final dictionary I want to obtain is

```
#dd
{
    0: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    1: [1, 2, 3],
}
```

I have tried to create a new list with all the values and extract those values with the correct indexes, but don't understand how to create the dictionary again with the corresponding keys and values on each object.

```
final = []
for row in dd:
    final.extend(dd[row])

corrected_final = []
for idx in notna_idxs:
    corrected_final.append(final[idx])
```

Comment: Could you have `dd` with more than 2 keys?

Comment: Yes, the keys can be multiple. This is an extraction process and this dictionary is created based on an input. Sometimes it has 1 key, other times has 50...

Comment: Are numbers in `notna_idxs` always in order?

Comment: Yes they are ordered from lower to higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an infinite generator ([`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)) to keep track of the global position, and a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) for efficient membership test:

```
from itertools import count

S = set(notna_idxs)

c = count()

out = {k: [x for x in l if next(c) in S]
       for k, l in dd.items()}
```

*Note that I only test membership in `notna_idxs` here (which is enough if the two sets are complementary), if really you want to test using both lists you can add this condition.*

```
from itertools import count

S = set(notna_idxs)
S2 = set(na_idxs)

c = count()

out = {k: [x for x in l if next(c) in S and not in S2]
       for k, l in dd.items()}
```

Output:

```
{0: [1, 2, 3, 4],
 1: [1, 2, 3]}
```

Variant using a classical python loop:

```
notna_idxs = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8}
na_idxs = {0, 5, 9}

out = {}
idx = 0
for k, l in dd.items():
    out[k] = []
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        i += idx  # transform the local index into a global index
        if i in notna_idxs and i not in na_idxs:
            out[k].append(x)
    idx += len(l) # update global index
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It passed my head to create a solution with a counter but when I tried to implement it It never worked since it never passed through the > 4 indexes. The use of Counter() and next() is something I need to master!!

Comment: @JoseM.González you're welcome, note however that I'm using `itertools.count` here, not `collections.Counter` (very different things) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using `set` containment check (indices of each entry in `notna_idxs` set) and consecutive index augmentation/shift:

```
notna_idxs_set = set(notna_idxs)
res_d = {}
total_N = 0  # total number of values throughout all entries
for k, v in dd.items():
    res_d[k] = [n for i, n in enumerate(v, total_N) if i in notna_idxs_set]
    total_N += len(v)

print(res_d)
```

---

```
{0: [1, 2, 3, 4], 1: [1, 2, 3]}
```